# Why browser always stop working when do while

Tags: javascript

Whats wrong with that? Why my browser always stuck here?

```
var n = 50;
while (n) {n++;}
```

How i did get it for myself browser must do just one cycle there.. But it stuck..

p.s what i wanted to get - just one cycle, when n will be 51..

Comment: it's an infinite loop

Comment: to get 51 from 50 do: `n++;` and remove the `while`

Comment: yes, but it is just experiments with while.. so i just wanted to make one cycle with while and as a result to get 51..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to use a cycle to get the value to 51? Simply assign

```
n = 51;
```

Anyway, if you REALLY need it (which I highly doubt), what you are looking for is:

```
while (n < 51) n++;
```

Comment: ahh, i see, it seems much better. Now i understood my fall

Answer (score 0):

The condition is always true so it will loop forever.
Try this

```
var n = 50;
while (n) {n--;}
```

This will decrement the value of n all the way to 0, where it will end.

Comment: So, it is not actually what i wanted to get.. How to get just one cycle? to make n = 51?